# Returning a HashMap collection with simple property keys in QueryDsl

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

In Querydsl, I would like to return a simple `Map<String, Object>` collection.  I imagine there's a simple way to do it.  I've used QMap, but it returns keys as fully qualified properties instead of simple properties.

So instead of items looking like this using a QMap collection:

```
{
    poolMaster.calculateValue: "Y"
    poolMaster.downloadStats: "Y"
    poolMaster.maxPlayerValue: 25
    poolMaster.minPlayerValue: 5
    poolMaster.pickDeadline: 1430366400000
    size(poolMaster.poolSequences): 1
    poolMaster.year: 2015
}
```

I'd like to get items that look like this:

```
{
    calculateValue: "Y"
    downloadStats: "Y"
    maxPlayerValue: 25
    minPlayerValue: 5
    pickDeadline: 1430366400000
    poolSequencesCount: 1
    year: 2015
}
```

This is my elaborate solution so far, but I'm hoping Querydsl has something already built in.

```
public Collection<Map<String, Object>> findAll() {
    return this.from(poolMaster)
            .orderBy(poolMaster.year.desc())
            .list(
                    map(
                            poolMaster.year, poolMaster.pickDeadline, poolMaster.downloadStats,
                            poolMaster.calculateValue, poolMaster.minPlayerValue, poolMaster.maxPlayerValue,
                            poolMaster.poolSequences.size()
                    )
            ).stream()
            .map(toHashMap())
            .collect(toList());
}

public static Function<Map<Expression<?>, ?>, Map<String, Object>> toHashMap() {
    return expressionMap -> {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Expression<?> key : expressionMap.keySet()) {
            Path path = null;
            String suffix = "";

            if(key instanceof NumberOperation) {
                NumberOperation op = (NumberOperation) key;

                if(op.getOperator().getId().equals(Ops.COL_SIZE.getId())) {
                    suffix = "Count";
                }

                path = (Path) op.getArg(0);
            }

            if(key instanceof Path) {
                path = (Path) key;
            }

            if(path != null) {
                map.put(path.getMetadata().getName() + suffix, expressionMap.get(key));
            }
        }
        return map;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to get a `Map <String, Map <String, String>>` and I succeeded as follows:

```
return new JPAQuery<Map<String, Map>>(getEm())
                        .from(qclasss)
                        .where(conditions)
                        .transform(groupBy(qclasss.propertyKey).as(map(qclasss.property1, qclasss.property2)));
```

the return of this is in this format:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "property1": "property1Value",
    "property2": "property2Value"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `FactoryExpression` interface to implement the transformation. That should be more performant and also compliant with how transformations are done in Querydsl.

Map like transformations for results are already available via `QTuple` and `QMap`. The sources of these two classes should give you some direction on how to create your map transformation.